# Linux Centos5 lockup - possibly a memory issue?

Tags: linux, centos5

Here is an OCR of a screenshot of a VPS hosted Centos5 64 bit Linux server that has just frozen up on me.  I have now rebooted this VPS guest but would appreciate it if anyone who understands the following could advise what might have caused the lockup?

The screenshot is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVSs8.png

And my rough OCR is below:

`cpu 1 cold: high 0, batch 1 used:0 
DMA32 per-cpu:
cpu 0 hot: high 186, batch 31 used:29 
cpu 0 cold: high 62, batch 15 used:27 
cpu 1 hot: high 186, batch 31 used:58 
cpu 1 cold: high 62, batch 15 used:52 
Normal per-cpu: empty 
HighMem per-cpu: empty 
Free pages: 7360kB (31KB HighMem) 
Active:127313 inactive:82099 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0 free:1840 slab:18478 mapped-file:546 mapped-anon:210605 pagetables:14991 
DMA free:3240kB min:32kB low:40kB high:48kB active:0kB inactive:0kB present:9052H pages_scanned:0 all_unreclairnable? yes 
lowmem reserve[]: 0 1002 1002 1002 
DMA32 free:4120kB min:4032kB low:5040kB high:6048kB active:509272kB inactive:328376kB present:102616 afl pages_scanned :2342 all_unreclairnable, no 
lowmem_reserve[] : 0 0 0 0 
Normal free:0kB min:0kB low:0kB high:0kB active:0kB inactive:0kB present:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unr eclaimable? no 
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 
HighMem free:0kB min: 128kB low : 128kB high :128kB active:0kB inactive:0kB present :0kB pages_scanned:0 I all_unreclaimable? no 
lowmem reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 
DMA: 0.4kB 1.8kB 2.16kB 2.321,B 1.64kB 2.128kB 1.256kB 1.512kB ,1024kB 0.2048kB 0.4096kB = 3240kB DMA32: 68.4kB 1.8kB 2.16kB 57.3aB 9.64kB 1.128kB 1.256kB 0.512kB 1.1024kB 0.2048kB 0.4096kB = 4120k 
Normal : empty 
HighMem: empty 
6100 pagecache pages 
swap cache: add 15557050, delete 15551562, find 330898601/333226192, race 14.1430 
Free swap = 0kB 
Total swap = 1048568kB`

Comment: You ran out of memory (and swap) and Linux started killing processes to free up RAM.  Monitor your system's RAM usage and look at what's eating up all your RAM when you get alerted that you're starting to run low on available memory.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a close eye on your swap-usage (or just start logging it).

If you don't have any monitoring tools (like `sar`) at your disposal, put the script below in cron and have it run once a minute.

**Cron Job**

```
#minute (0-59),
#|  hour (0-23),
#|  |  day of the month (1-31),
#|  |  |  month of the year (1-12),
#|  |  |  |  day of the week (0-6, 0=Sun)
#|  |  |  |  |  commands
*   *  *  *  * /path/to/cronjob-check_swap.ksh >> /path/to/check_swap.log
```

**CronJob-Check_Swap.ksh**

```
## Script to call the check_swap.ksh script & Date/Time stamp the output
$DATECMD="date" ## Modify to get a date/time stamp in the format you like
printf "`$DATECMD` : `/path/to/check_swap.ksh`"
```

**Check_Swap.ksh (For Linux,Solaris & HP-UX 11.11)**

```
#!/bin/ksh
# check_swap.ksh
#   Outputs swap usage in a human-readable one-liner.
#   Used to quickly check a system's swap.
#
#   Works on the following platforms;
#    HP-UX B.11.11 on PA-RISC
#    SunOS 5.10 on SPARC (global zone)
#    SunOS 5.10 on SPARC (non-global)
#    RHEL5/6 on x86 & x86_64
#    
##############################################################################
## GENERIC ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
#     The full paths of things. Should be consistent across all platforms.
OSTYPE=$( /bin/uname )
PRINTF=/usr/bin/printf
GREP=/bin/grep
ECHO=/bin/echo
AWK=/bin/awk
SED=/bin/sed
##############################################################################
## SPECIFIC ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
#     Variables used for this script
SWAP_TOTAL=0
SWAP_USED=0
SWAP_FREE=0
PERCENT_USED=0
PERCENT_FREE=0
##############################################################################
## DEBUG 
#     A function that we sprinkle in our script to show us the raw vars.
DEBUG(){
   ${PRINTF} "=====  DEBUG =====\n"
   [ -z ${OSTYPE} ]   || ${PRINTF} "                  OSTYPE = ${OSTYPE} \n"
   [ -z ${DATETIME} ] || ${PRINTF} "             Date / Time = ${DATETIME} \n"
   [ -z ${SWAP} ]     || ${PRINTF} "            Swap Command = ${SWAP} \n"
   [ -z ${SOD_T} ]    || ${PRINTF} " Swap-On-Disk Total (MB) = ${SOD_T} \n"
   [ -z ${SOD_F} ]    || ${PRINTF} " Swap-On-Disk Free  (MB) = ${SOD_F} \n"
   [ -z ${SOD_U} ]    || ${PRINTF} " Swap-On-Disk Used  (MB) = ${SOD_U} \n"
   [ -z ${STMP} ]     || ${PRINTF} "    Swap Total/Used (MB) = ${STMP} \n"
   ${PRINTF} "=====  DEBUG =====\n"
}
##############################################################################
## THRESHOLD CONTROLS - Where we define our thresholds and color-coding.
#  
# Colors
  cf="\033[0m"  # Color Off
  hi="\033[31m" # Red
  lo="\033[33m" # Yellow
  go="\033[32m" # green
# Thresholds
TH_PR="10:20"
TH_SZ="512:1024"
##############################################################################
## SWAP_ON_DISK - calculates the usage of swap devices
#  stu  (Swap Total, Used ) = "Total:Used" in Blocks (if needed).
#  stmp (Swap Temp)         = "Total:Used" in KiloBytes.
#  STMP (Swap Temp)         = "Total:Used" in MegaBytes.
SWAP_ON_DISK(){
  case ${OSTYPE} in
    # Solaris reports swap statistics in blocks (512 bytes = 1 block).
    SunOS)
      # Our command to query swap-on-disk
      SWAP="/usr/sbin/swap -l"
      sod_tf=$(${SWAP}|${AWK} '!/swaplo/{t+=$4;f+=$5}END{printf"%.f:%.f",t,f}')
      # Swap-on-Disk Total (Megabytes)
      SOD_T=$(( ( ( ${sod_tf%%:*} * 512 ) / 1024 ) / 1024 )) 
      # Swap-On-Disk Free (Megabytes)
      SOD_F=$(( ( ( ${sod_tf#*:}  * 512 ) / 1024 ) / 1024 )) 
      # Swap-On-Disk Used (already in Megabytes)
      SOD_U=$(( ${SOD_T} - ${SOD_F} ))
      #  STMP (Swap Temp)  = "Total:Used" in MegaBytes.
      STMP=${SOD_T}:${SOD_U}
      ;;
    # HP-UX reports swap usage in kilobytes by default.
    HP-UX)
      # Our command to query swap-on-disk
      SWAP="/usr/sbin/swapinfo -tdfm"
      # Swap Temp  = "Total:Used" (in MB)
      STMP=$( ${SWAP}|${AWK} '/total/{t+=$2;u+=$3}END{printf"%.f:%.f",t,u}')
      ;;
    #  Linux reports swap usage in kilobytes by default.
    Linux)
      # Our command to query swap-on-disk (can't use 'free -om', its a RHELism)
      SWAP="/sbin/swapon -s"
      sod_tu=$(${SWAP}|${AWK} '!/File/{t+=$3;u+=$4}END{printf"%.f:%.f",t,u}')
      sod_t=$(( ${sod_tu%%:*} / 1024 ))
      sod_u=$(( ${sod_tu#*:}  / 1024 ))
      STMP=${sod_t}:${sod_u}
      ;;
  esac
}
##############################################################################
## SWAP_AND_RESERVE - checks swap just like top, glance and HP OMW
#                     Basically, this counts the 'Reserve' of RAM as well.
#  NOTE:  On a Solaris Non-Global Zone, the 'Reserve' is defined from the
#         Global Zone, and is shared amongst each NGZ.
#         This makes this check come back 'weird' sometimes.
#         (Especially when the 'Reserve' is 25GB, which counts as 'used' swap,
#         while the NGZ itself only has 4GB or 8GB of swap from a disk.
SWAP_RESERVE(){
  case ${OSTYPE} in
    SunOS)
      # Our command to pull the 'swap summary' (includes the Reserve in RAM)
      SWAP="/usr/sbin/swap -s"
      sr_uf=$( ${SWAP}|${AWK} '{print $9":"$11}'|${SED} -e 's/k//g' )
      # Swap+Reserve Used  (in MB)
      SR_U=$(( ${sr_uf%%:*} / 1024 ))
      # Swap+Reserve Free  (in MB)
      SR_F=$(( ${sr_uf#*:} / 1024 ))
      # Swap+Reserve Total (in MB) (Sum of Used & Free)
      SR_T=$(( ${SR_U} + ${SR_F} ))
      # Swap Temp  = "Total:Used" (in MB)
      STMP=${SR_T}:${SR_U}
      ;;
    *)
      STMP=""
      ;;
  esac
}
##############################################################################
## FORMAT - splits all the vars and makes em pretty
#           Requires STMP be set, and should be "Total:Used" (we calc 'Free')
FORMAT(){
  SWAP_TOTAL=${STMP%%:*}
  SWAP_USED=${STMP#*:}
  SWAP_FREE=$(( ( ${SWAP_TOTAL} - ${SWAP_USED} ) ))
  #  Put a pretty comma every 3 digits.
  ST="`${ECHO} ${SWAP_TOTAL}|${SED} -e :a -e 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1,\2/;ta'`"
  SF="`${ECHO} ${SWAP_FREE} |${SED} -e :a -e 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1,\2/;ta'`"
  SU="`${ECHO} ${SWAP_USED} |${SED} -e :a -e 's/\(.*[0-9]\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1,\2/;ta'`"
  #  Calculate Percentages
  PERCENT_FREE=$(( ( ${SWAP_FREE} * 100 ) / ${SWAP_TOTAL} ))
  PERCENT_USED=$(( ( ${SWAP_USED} * 100 ) / ${SWAP_TOTAL} ))
  PF=${PERCENT_FREE}
  PU=${PERCENT_USED}
}
##############################################################################
## SCRIPT - Yay! Here we do stuff!
# Our command to query swap.
case ${OSTYPE} in
  SunOS)
    SWAP="/usr/sbin/swap -l"
    ;;
  HP-UX)
    SWAP="/usr/sbin/swapinfo -tdfm"
    ;;
  Linux)
    # (can't use 'free -om', its a RHELism)
    SWAP="/sbin/swapon -s"
    ;;
  *)
    ${PRINTF} "Unsupported OS ${OSTYPE}.\n"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
# Verify we can query swap
  if [ ! -x ${SWAP%% *} ]; then
     ${PRINTF} "${SWAP%% *} not found or not executable by us.\n"
     exit 1
  fi
#
# Need a 'do we even have any swap to query' check here.
#
SWAP_ON_DISK
# DEBUG
[[ -z ${STMP} ]] || FORMAT
# DEBUG
[[ -z ${STMP} ]] || ${PRINTF} \
"Swap-on-Disk: ${SF}mb free (${PF}%%) of ${ST}mb total. ${SU}mb used (${PU}%%).
"
SWAP_RESERVE
[[ -z ${STMP} ]] || FORMAT
[[ -z ${STMP} ]] || ${PRINTF} \
"Swap+Reserve: ${SF}mb free (${PF}%%) of ${ST}mb total. ${SU}mb used (${PU}%%).
"
# EoF
```